# Flow Screen to manage related records in a collection

Tags: screen-flow

I am trying to think through how to create a straightforward, user-friendly screen to manage a collection of records. The client prototype is pasted below. The user will add 1-6 time and date entries which will reside in (and be pre-filled by) a custom object. I could just set it up with 18 variables and use looping and assignment to populate from existing records, and a series of create records elements to create records from the 18 variables. This is pretty straightforward for the user, but a bit of a mess on the back end.

I can imagine a data table of existing records, with options to edit existing entries or add new lines, but I'm hoping to find an example that makes that process clean for the user, as well as allowing them to move on to the next screen when the user is satisfied that all their data is properly entered.

I'd just as soon not be building LWCs but willing to consider it if there's a good model to work from.

Thoughts?

[image: table with 6 data rows, and columns for hours, dates, and modality]

Comment: what is the underlying database schema here?  Is an Engagement_NN_ row represent one Engagement__c object with three fields: Hours, Date, Modality)?

Comment: Yes, each row will be its own record with those three fields. They are loaded into the flow as a collection of records of type Engagement__c.

Comment: so why can't you use a Data Grid component in the screen flow?

Comment: Do you mean the standard Data Table? Or is there another component I should be looking at? I don't see Data Grid in a quick search. I've looked at data table but don't see a clean way for users to either add or edit lines. It seems likely that I'll try to adapt this LWC to my needs - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XvbXQAS

Comment: I misspoke, i did mean Data Table or the [UnofficialSf.com Data Table](https://unofficialsf.com/datatable-lightning-web-component-for-flow-screens-2/). I guess I envisioned an Add button that allowed user to enter new row and by clicking NEXT, the table refreshed. The LWC approach would work. also, if Engagement__c is a child of something else, you could try [SmartLists](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000HEZW9UAP), an SFDC Labs component